# When does the inverse image functor commute with internal hom?

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

For a map of topological spaces $j: X \to Y$, when do we have $j^{-1}RHom(\mathcal{F}^{\circ}, \mathcal{G}^{\circ}) \cong RHom(j^{-1}\mathcal{F}^{\circ},j^{-1}\mathcal{G}^{\circ})$? All constructions are taking place in $X$ and $Y$'s respective derived categories of sheaves. Although I'm not sure, I suspect one can answer the question for ordinary sheaves and then extrapolate to the derived setting.

Note this is true for $\mathcal{F}$ finitely presented and $X$ a point, since in that case $j^{-1}$ is just the stalk functor.

Comment: A slight variation: (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6I)

Comment: Are you looking for condition on $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ or on $X,Y,j$ ? or both ? The statement holds unconditionally if $j$ is an open immersion (or more generally a local isomorphism), and this holds even for the underived version. This should also work for $j$ topologically smooth (that is locally the projection of a topological manifold), in this case this works only in the derived category. Finally, if $\mathcal{F}$ is finitely presented, as you said, this works for stalks, since you can check such an isomorphism looking only at stalks, it should hold for any immersion.

Comment: As a side note, the projection formula gives an isomorphism
$$ RHom(j^{-1}\mathcal{F}^\circ,j^!\mathcal{G}^\circ)\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}j^!RHom(\mathcal{F}^\circ,\mathcal{G}^\circ)$$ which holds as long as $j^!$ exists. If $j$ is a local isomorphism $j^{-1}=j^!$, if $j$ is a topologically smooth, $j^{-1}=j^!\otimes\mathfrak{or}[-n]$.

Comment: @Roland I'm more interested in conditions on $X$ and $Y$ and $j$, although conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are helpful as well. What is a topologically smooth morphism? I'm aware of a smooth morphism in the algebraic geometry sense but I've never heard of "topological smoothness"

Comment: I don't think this is standard terminology, but as I said, topologically smooth = locally the projection of a topological manifold. In a differential setting, it corresponds to submersions, and in the algebraic setting, this corresponds to smooth morphisms.

Comment: @Roland I don't know how I missed that before, thanks. I think the proof for immersions is straight forward, but how do you go about proving it in the case of $j$ smooth?

Comment: Using Verdier duality as I suggested : $j^{-1}=j^!\otimes\mathfrak{or}[-n]$ and the result for $j^!$.

Comment: This isomorphism holds in the case of a topological submersion as seen in Proposition 3.3.2 of Kashiwara-Schapira *Sheaves on Manifolds*, as described above, but it holds more generally in the case of an immersion when the complex of sheaves has locally constant cohomology — see Proposition 4.3.6 and the results that precede and succeed it in Dimca’s *Sheaves in Topology*.

Comment: @leibnewtz check Kashiwara-Schapira "Sheaves on Manifolds", exercice VI.4 for conditions on the microsupport of $F$ and $G$ to get the isomorphism